# Comparing data field to today's date - Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have a date field called Acceptance_Date.

`Acceptance_Date = 10/10/2011` (MM/DD/YYYY)

I have to compare Acceptance_Date to Sysdate and return true or false.

How can I compare dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Acceptance_Date is of type Date:

```
select decode(Acceptance_Date, trunc(sysdate), 1, 0)
from table
```

else, add to_date(Acceptance_Date,'mm/dd/yyyy') instead of just Acceptance_Date

Comment: I went with to_date. Thanks for your support.